# Broadcast Receiver not receivng Broadcasts

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I seem to be having trouble getting my onReceive class receive any broadcasts I send out. Im not sure if its my code thats the problem or its a problem with the Android Manifest.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("BROADCAST_RECEIVED", intent.getDataString());
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        wakeLock.release();
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

---

```
public void setDayOfWeekAlarm(DayOfWeek day){
    long alarmInMili = 0;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,AlarmScreenActivity.class);
    alarmInMili = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*10;
    Log.i("REGISTER ALARM", String.valueOf(alarmInMili));
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
            10 * 1000,pi);
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brianlindsey.alarm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name="com.brianlindsey.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gabe's answer, the `Intent` that you are using in `setDayOfWeekAlarm()` points to `AlarmScreenActivity`. That is not your `BroadcastReceiver`, nor is it any other component registered in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

BOOT_COMPLETED receivers cannot recieve a broadcast until an activity in the apk has been launched at least once.  Its a weird rule google added to prevent people from downloading an app by mistake and having it run at boot.

Comment: It's not so much "downloading an app by mistake" as it is "preventing drive-by malware". Once the Play Store had a Web site, now users are one hacked set of Google credentials away from having any app installed on their device, without their on-device approval.

Comment: That sounds more like a flaw in ANdroid that there's any way to install an app without a direct action from the user.  It still seems to me to be an odd way to have fixed the flaw, as it still allows installation of the app (which will likely eventually be run as a user will sometime see the icon and go "what's this?").

Comment: "that there's any way to install an app without a direct action from the user" -- not really. Again, the issue is hacked Google credentials. From Google's standpoint, the user *did* install the app, as Google has no way to tell the user from the person using the hacked credentials.

Comment: @GabeSechan : It's not such a "weird rule". Think of it like this...even an Android device which is a phone is also 99% computer. At one time the most prevalent computer viruses (on DOS & Windows PCS at least) were ones which infected the MBR (Master Boot Record). In some ways the unrestricted use of `BOOT_COMPLETED` could potentially allow unauthorised software to become active similar to boot sector viruses on PCs. Android may be flawed in a number of ways but *ANY* restriction of malware potentially acting in an automated way has to better than none.